# recover ubuntu after accidentlly using rm -r * in / directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I accidentally did `rm -r *` in my / directory of ubuntu machine as root login.
Now when I am trying to restart my machine its saying

```
error file not found
GRUB RESCUE>
```

can my machine be recovered or its data which is very important?
please help !!!

Comment: You can not recover the system but you may be able to recover some of your files. Try photorec.

Comment: If your system doesn't boot, but your data are on the same partition, connect your hard-disk to another machne, or boot from a live CD.
If you can see the data..  its easy.
If you can't see the data, then you need to use Ext partition data undelete recovery tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to boot from a [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) but there is no guaranteed way to recover your files.